# Magento 1.7.0 - Techinical datasheet path location in database

Tags: magento-1.7

I need to find out which table or tables which holds the technical datasheet path location in the database.

I need to change the path values for each technical datasheet. as there are over a thousand products i can only do this via the database.

I cant seem to find any results on the web.
Magento 1.7.0
Thanks

**Location on the datsheet link:**

**1. Click General**
[image]

**2. In the General section**

[image]

Comment: The attribute seems to be created by an extension ... Ify so, please post config.xml (I guess only file name is store in DB - not full path)

Comment: Someone flagged this question, which was both obviously answered by OP. Shame.

Answer (score 1):

**I managed to solve this by using the following queries:**

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar;
SELECT * FROM eav_entity_type;
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute;

SELECT *
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
WHERE entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product') 
AND attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'pdf_document' AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
```

Once executed i manually changed the paths in the database